# Functional tests (Jellytools) don't start on netbeans platform

Tags: java, maven, testing, netbeans, netbeans-platform

I'm trying to add some functional tests on existing netbeans application.
**Info about application**: packaged by maven, used netbeans platform 7.3.1.
I've added dependencies how described in this [article](https://dzone.com/articles/nb-mvn-functional-tests)  but got exception:

```
Running qa.FuncTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.067 sec <<< FAILURE! - in qa.FuncTest
org.netbeans.junit.NbModuleSuite$S@67ad77a7(org.netbeans.junit.NbModuleSuite$S)  Time elapsed: 0.066 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.netbeans.Main
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.netbeans.junit.NbModuleSuite$S.runInRuntimeContainer(NbModuleSuite.java:819)
    at org.netbeans.junit.NbModuleSuite$S.access$100(NbModuleSuite.java:667)
```

Does anybody know why it happend? And how to fix it?
Thanks in advance.

**UPD** dependency section from application/pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.netbeans.cluster</groupId>
        <artifactId>platform</artifactId>
        <version>${software.netbeans.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>org-jdesktop-beansbinding</artifactId>
        <version>${software.netbeans.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>org-netbeans-modules-nbjunit</artifactId>
        <version>${software.netbeans.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>org-netbeans-modules-jellytools-platform</artifactId>
        <version>${software.netbeans.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**UPD1** test class:

```
package qa;

import junit.framework.Test;
import org.netbeans.jellytools.JellyTestCase;
import org.netbeans.jellytools.OptionsOperator;
import org.netbeans.junit.NbModuleSuite;
import org.openide.windows.TopComponent;

public class FuncTest extends JellyTestCase {

    public static Test suite() {
        return NbModuleSuite.allModules(FuncTest.class);
    }

    public FuncTest(String n) {
        super(n);
    }

    public void testWhatever() throws Exception {
        TopComponent tc = new TopComponent();
        tc.setName("label");
        tc.open();
        OptionsOperator.invoke().selectMiscellaneous();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.err.println("OK.");
    }
}
```

Comment: please share the dependencies used in your pom.xml

Comment: @nullpointer added in update

Comment: and your java class please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to share results of my investigation. I noticed when application was started as usual i saw in output window:

```
  Installation            =.../application/target/application/extra
                           .../application/target/application/java
                           .../application/target/application/kws
                           .../application/target/application/platform
```

but when application was started via nbjubit/jellytool i saw only:

```
  Installation            =.../application/target/application/platform
```

so i decided to expand this values and investigated source code. Let's consider a few interesting methods in NbModuleSuite.java :

```
    private static String[] tokenizePath(String path) {
        List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
        StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(path, ":;", true); // NOI18N


    .....
        }

static File findPlatform() {
        String clusterPath = System.getProperty("cluster.path.final"); // NOI18N
        if (clusterPath != null) {
            for (String piece : tokenizePath(clusterPath)) {
                File d = new File(piece);
                if (d.getName().matches("platform\\d*")) {
                    return d;
                }
            }
        }
        String allClusters = System.getProperty("all.clusters"); // #194794
        if (allClusters != null) {
            File d = new File(allClusters, "platform"); // do not bother with old numbered variants
            if (d.isDirectory()) {
                return d;
            }
        }


    ....
        }

static void findClusters(Collection<File> clusters, List<String> regExps) throws IOException {
        File plat = findPlatform().getCanonicalFile();
        String selectiveClusters = System.getProperty("cluster.path.final"); // NOI18N
        Set<File> path;
        if (selectiveClusters != null) {
            path = new TreeSet<File>();
            for (String p : tokenizePath(selectiveClusters)) {
                File f = new File(p);
                path.add(f.getCanonicalFile());
            }
        } else {
            File parent;
            String allClusters = System.getProperty("all.clusters"); // #194794
            if (allClusters != null) {
                parent = new File(allClusters);
            } else {
                parent = plat.getParentFile();
            }
            path = new TreeSet<File>(Arrays.asList(parent.listFiles()));
        }


....
        }
```

As you can see we can set path values in `cluster.path.final` or `all.clusters` and use `;` `:` as delimeters. I spent some time to play with this constants and realised that settings didn't set up in pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${software.maven-surefire-plugin}</version>
    <configuration>
        <skipTests>false</skipTests>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <branding.token>${brandingToken}</branding.token>
            <!--problem part start-->
            <property>
                <name>cluster.path.final</name>
                <value>${project.build.directory}/${brandingToken}/platform:${project.build.directory}/${brandingToken}/java:...etc</value>
            </property>
            <!--problem part end-->
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

but this work well:

```
<properties>
    <cluster.path.final>${project.build.directory}/${brandingToken}/platform:${project.build.directory}/${brandingToken}/java:...etc</cluster.path.final>
</properties>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${software.maven-surefire-plugin}</version>
    <configuration>
        <skipTests>false</skipTests>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <branding.token>${brandingToken}</branding.token>
            <cluster.path.final>${cluster.path.final}</cluster.path.final>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I don't know why it happens but I would recommend to use maven section `properties` to set systemPropertyVariables of maven-surefire-plugin. Good luck!

Comment: @All_Safe Sorry I can't provide full pom.xml, now I don't have. Note: It's international site so please don't use Russian